# drop a database in delphi via SQL statement and adoquery

Tags: delphi

I want to drop a database via an sql statement, my code goes like this  using delphi XE and ADO for DB access, server is MSSQL

```
  aDBConnection.ConnectionString :=  'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated    

                   Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog='
                   + DatabaseName + '; Data Source=' + Servername;      

  aDBConnection.Connected := true;  

  aQuery.Connection := aDBConnection;

  aQuery.add.sql (' drop database ' + DatabaseName );

  aQuery.Execsql.
```

running many other sql statements with this code sequence is fine, but he refused to drop the database as the claims "database is in use".

Guess this is true as I really have one connection to the database, but how to do other, I need the query to send the sql to the server ...

Comment: Change `Initial Catalog` to `master` and you should get it to work.

Comment: is there any value in the TAdoconnection which I also must take care in order not to keep an existing connection to the database, except connected := false ??

Comment: if I run now the solution with Initial catalog = master this work but only if i do not connect to the database I want to delete before. I use this db-connection like first create database ... work on the database and in the end drop the database; create and work is fine, but then I can not delete. restart the program and only execute delete database also works fine

Comment: Have you closed all datasets ? I don't know if opened datasets are problem. The only thing I know is that you must [`USE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx) a different database in order to delete one. So, sorry, I can't help you more with it (I can't even test since I don't have any SQL Server available now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not need to close the connnection explicit, as mentioned by TLama all you need is [USE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx) to change your connection. There is also no need for closing of the Datasets, except they are opened with *CursorLocation := clUseServer;* Even after changing to *master* (Button_ChangeToMasterClick) you will be able to edit already opened datasets, but since CursorLocation is clUseClient, youe even will be able to DROP the database. Editing after dropping naturally leads to an error.

```
Const
 aDatabaseName='DeleteMeAfterUse';

procedure TForm3.ButtonCreateOpen_Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Ads: TAdodataset;
begin
  AC.ConnectionString := 'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=master;Data Source=127.0.0.1';
  AC.Connected := true;
  AC.Execute('Create DataBase ' + aDatabaseName);
  AC.Execute('Use ' + aDatabaseName);  // change connection to 'DeleteMeAfterUse'
  AC.Execute('Create Table Test (ID int)'); // will be created in DeleteMeAfterUse
  AC.Execute('Insert into Test Values (1)');
  Ads := TAdodataset.Create(self); // Display data on surface
  // Ads.CursorLocation := clUseServer;  **
  // ** don't use clUseServer if you want to delete the database without closing the datasets
  // default is clUseClient

  With Ads do
  begin
    Connection := AC;
    CommandText := 'Select * from Test';
    Active := true;
  end;
  DataSource1.DataSet := Ads; // Conected to a DBGrid for editing
end;

procedure TForm3.Button_ChangeToMasterClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AC.Execute('Use master');  // change connection to master , any other database will work too
end;

procedure TForm3.Button_DropDatabaseClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AC.Execute('Drop Database ' + aDatabaseName);
end;
```

Comment: in my code this is still not working (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005843/database-testclass-shows-strange-behaviour-at-unit-testing ). the TTestdatabase class has further issues .. may be this is the reason why i can not use the proposed solution