# Database Testclass shows strange behaviour at unit testing

Tags: delphi

I want to design an abstract class to impelement unit testing on database releated function in my application. 
If I call the CreateDatabase or  ConnectToExistingDatabase I want to store the database information in the private section of my class

```
type
  TTestDatabase = class
    FDatabaseConnection: TADOConnection;
  private
    FServerName: string;
    FDatabaseName: string;
    FPathtoSqlScripts: string;
  public
    procedure CreateDatabase(AServerName, ADatabaseName,
      APathtoSqlScripts: string);
    procedure ConnectToExistingDatabase(AServerName, ADatabaseName: string);
    function DropDatabase: Boolean;
  end; 

procedure TTestDatabase.ConnectToExistingDatabase(AServerName,
  ADatabaseName: string);
begin
  FServerName := AServerName;
  FDatabaseName := ADatabaseName;
  ConnecttoDatabase(FServerName, FDatabaseName, FDatabaseConnection);
end;

constructor TTestDatabase.Create;
begin
  FDatabaseConnection := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
end;

procedure TTestDatabase.CreateDatabase(AServerName, ADatabaseName,
  APathtoSqlScripts: string);
var
  aSql: string;
begin
  FServerName := AServerName;
  FDatabaseName := ADatabaseName;
  FPathtoSqlScripts := APathtoSqlScripts;
  ADO_CreateDatabase(FDatabaseName, FServerName);  
end;

function TTestDatabase.DropDatabase: Boolean;
var
  aSql: string;
begin
  // connect new to server
  FServerName := MYSERVER;
  FDatabaseConnection.Connected := False;
  ConnecttoDatabase(FServerName, 'master', FDatabaseConnection);
  // drop the database
  FDatabaseName := 'TEST_DATABASE';

  if (FDatabaseName <> '') then
  begin
    FDatabaseConnection.Execute('use master');
    aSql := ' drop database ' + FDatabaseName;
    FDatabaseConnection.Execute(aSql);
  end
  else
    Result := False;
end;
```

The problem:  the values FDatabasename .... are always empty strings if it comes to run the dropdatabase function. If I redefine eg. FServername (as shown in the code example) the problem is solved, but this an not acceptable solution ....

Can I not store values in the private section of a class while executing unit test function ????

THis is the unit test code , not yet complete. Hope it will show the problem

```
procedure TestTTestDatabase.TestCreateDatabase;
var
  aServerName: string;
  aDatabaseName: string;
  aPathtoSqlScripts: string;
begin
  // TODO: Setup method call parameters
  aServerName := MYSERVER;
  aDatabaseName := 'TEST_UNITTEST';
  aPathtoSqlScripts  := 'C:\testpath\';

  FTestDatabase.CreateDatabase(aServerName, aDatabaseName, aPathtoSqlScripts);
  // TODO: Validate method results
end;

procedure TestTTestDatabase.TestConnectToExistingDatabase;
var
  aServerName: string;
  aDatabaseName: string;
begin
  // TODO: Setup method call parameters
  aServerName := MYSERVER;
  aDatabaseName := 'TEST_UNITTEST';

  try
    FTestDatabase.ConnectToExistingDatabase(aServerName, aDatabaseName);
  except
    fail('connection to exception fails');
  end;
  // TODO: Validate method results
  CheckTrue(FTestDatabase.Connection);
end;

procedure TestTTestDatabase.TestDropDatabase;
var
  ReturnValue: Boolean;
begin
  ReturnValue := FTestDatabase.DropDatabase;
  // TODO: Validate method results
end;
```

Comment: Where do you create the `FTestDatabase`? In the `setup` method? You do know that that would create an entirely new instance for each of your testmethods? *(nothing wrong with that but your `TestDropDatabase` method would be working on a `FTestDatabase` that has not set `FDatabase`)*

Comment: The first part of your code is incomplete. Missing : ConnecttoDatabase, ADO_CreateDatabase and MYSERVER

Comment: constructor TTestDatabase.Create;
begin
  FDatabaseConnection := TADIConnection.Create(nil);
end;

Comment: did not post the functions code ConnecttoDatabase, ADO_CreateDatabase ,  they are working  in several other projects without any problem

Comment: do I have to create my TTestDatabaseClass in every unittest function?  , CAn I keep my testclass alive between different unit tests ?

Comment: @user1769184 - You don't have to but it is encouraged. Keeping a fixture *(class to be tested)* alive between different unit test methods, you could very well end up having multiple tests failing as the result of *one* misbehaving testmethod.

Comment: guess this is the source of my problems :  procedure TestTTestDatabase.SetUp;
begin
  FTestDatabase := TTestDatabase.Create;
end;

Comment: @user1769184 - Indeed <g>.